# Panorama with rectangular projection

Tags: panorama

I've taken about an hundered of pictures of a large painting with an iPhone at a distance of about 40cm. For each picture I moved the camera along the painting.

I was thinking to use [hugin](/questions/tagged/hugin) to build the final assembly. Unfortunately all the possible projections seems to apply only on a sphere not on a rectangle.

How can I automate the assembly of the painting I captured?

Comment: mosaic stitching mode?  see @jwpat7's answer: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25747/what-would-be-the-right-approach-to-take-pictures-of-a-long-counter

Comment: and this one: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14658/how-can-i-stitch-a-panorama-correctly-if-i-moved-the-camera-along-the-horizontal

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Rectilinear projection](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Rectilinear_Projection.html). It practice, it is usually hard to get right, since it tends to amplify mis-alignments of individual images.

See for example [this tutorial](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/Mosaic-mode/en.shtml) or [this one](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml) for an example of stitching flat images together.

Comment: Not sure about your answer `Rectilinear is a type of projection for mapping a portion of the surface of a sphere to a flat image`. I would like to map a portion of a flat image into a flat image.

Comment: The description assumes that you took all your pictures from the same point. I guess you moved your phone to remain parallel to the picture. I'll add more info in my answer.

Comment: In my Hugin version (latest), I don't have the same interface as your first tutorial. There is less tabs.

Comment: @nowox, select **Interface -> Expert** or **Interface -> Advanced**, and you should see the **Control Points**, **Masks**, **Optimizer**, and **Stitcher** tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows platform, try [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/ice/).
It has mode for this kind of stitching and it works quite well.