# How to make a photo of a wide wall

Tags: panorama

Let's say you need to take a photo of a 200 feet wide wall, but can't move further away from it than 50 feet (won't get the entire wall in one photo).

Currently, I stand still, and take a bunch of photos from side to side in a rotating motion, and then stitch them together (like a panorama function would do). But that gives a heavily distorted image.

I wish there was a panorama function that let you walk sideways along the wall, instead of using a rotating motion. Does this exist?
Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: What keeps you from doing just that? Walk along the wall and take the pictures, and then stitch them together?

Comment: Stitching software have problem making stiches. Sometimes it won't be able to stich them at all, and sometimes the stiching is not done very well (parts repeated).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a software that can make some kind of **stitching**.

It's not really a classical projection as those tend to project a sphere into something else (you generally take pictures using a tripod and just *rotate* the camera, not *moving* it).

You really don't want cylindrical projections (which are projections from a sphere to a plan) or cubic projection (projection from sphere to a cube). Examples of what you don't want here : http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Projections.html#Cylindrical_projections

What you want is a feature sometimes called "mosaic mode" or "stitching mode" in software.

For example, the software Hugin can do it (http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/Mosaic-mode/en.shtml). Windows offers ICE, a free tool (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/ice/).

I think your question is very close to [How can I stitch a panorama correctly if I moved the camera along the horizontal axis?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14658/how-can-i-stitch-a-panorama-correctly-if-i-moved-the-camera-along-the-horizontal), and similar to [What would be the right approach to take pictures of a long counter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25747/what-would-be-the-right-approach-to-take-pictures-of-a-long-counter) and [Panorama with rectangular projection](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67732/panorama-with-rectangular-projection).

For your purpose, the "best" way (IMHO) to take pictures dedicated to be stitched would be to walk sideways along the wall, taking pictures directly facing the wall (eventually using a tripod).